# How does HTTP Head request get the accurate content-type?

Tags: http, command-line, mime-types, media

I have a media server. I have files of different types uploaded there.

When I make a HEAD request, I get the Content-Type header in the response. I was wondering if the Media server uses the `file` command internally to get the Content-Type?

I have found that `file` command sometimes returns generic type like `application/octet-stream` for wmv or avi files.

Comment: It's totally up to the server about how it works. There is no generic answer to your question.

Comment: How reliable is that? What is the best way to get the mime type of a file? Because accordingly I will be processing it further. If it is an image, it will be processed differently than when its a video.

Comment: How reliable is _what_?

Comment: How reliable is the content-type returned in the HEAD request? I have been using a package that checks the mimetype once the file is downloaded. It is returning wrong type. For eg, for a .wmv video, the package returns  the mime type as audio/xyz instead of video/xyz. But the HEAD response content-type header returns it correctly.

Comment: It depends on the server, as you've been already told.

Comment: Got it. And there's no definitive way to get this info. Thank you.